# Check if two column match on SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where the user has to enter their reservation id and last name. If these two values match in the database then I need to return the corresponding values from the database.

I have two files, one that is html where I use ajax and one php file. When clicking on the button, nothing is being returned, I am not seeing any specific errors and I am sure that the value I put in are correct.

```
<script>
var ajax = getHTTPObject();

function getHTTPObject()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
      //alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function updateCityState()
{
    if (ajax)
    {
        var reservation_id = document.getElementById("reservation_id").value;
          var guest_last_name = document.getElementById("guest_last_name").value;

        if(reservation_id)
        {

            var param = "?reservation_id=" + reservation_id + "&guest_last_name=" + guest_last_name;
var url = "test04.php";

            ajax.open("GET", url + param, true);
            ajax.onreadystatechange = handleAjax;
            ajax.send(null);

        }
    }
}
function handleAjax()                                                                                                                           
{
  if (ajax.readyState == 4)
   {
        var guest_full_name = document.getElementById('guest_full_name');

            var unit_number = document.getElementById('unit_number');

    var floor = document.getElementById('floor');

        var key_sa = document.getElementById('key_sa');




    if(!!ajax.responseText) {
      var result = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
      if(!!result){
         guest_full_name.innerHTML  = (!!result.guest_full_name) ? result.guest_full_name : '';

             unit_number.innerHTML = (!!result.unit_number) ? result.unit_number : '';


        floor.innerHTML = (!!result.floor) ? result.floor : '';


        key_sa.innerHTML = (!!result.key_sa) ? result.key_sa : '';
      } 
    }
   }
 }
</script>



<p id='employee_name'></p>
<p id='employee_age'></p>
<p id='safe_code'></p>
```

My test04.php

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");

$reservation_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['reservation_id']);
$guest_last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['guest_last_name']);

$query = "SELECT reservation_id, guest_full_name, guest_last_name unit_number, floor, key_sa FROM reservations2 INNER JOIN guest ON (reservations2.reservation_id=guest.reservation_idg) INNER JOIN unit USING (unit_id) where reservation_id ='".$reservation_id."'AND guest_last_name ='".$guest_last_name."";


 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error());
$response = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {



        $response['guest_full_name'] = ($row['guest_full_name'] != '') ? $row['guest_full_name'] : '';
         $response['unit_number'] = ($row['unit_number'] != '') ? $row['unit_number'] : '';

             $response['floor'] = ($row['floor'] != '') ? $row['floor'] : '';
        $response['key_sa'] = ($row['key_sa'] != '') ? $row['key_sa'] : '';



    }
}
echo  json_encode($response, true); 


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not seeing any specific errors

- Where are you looking?
- Did you check the raw response from the PHP script or just look at what was rendered in your browser?
- Did you verify that error logging is working and did you check your logs?

The logic of your PHP is unclear - your JSON data and the PHP array can't handle multiple records yet you process multiple records. It would be nice to implement REST properly. This should also apply authentication and use CSRF for security - but I'll assume you left those out for illustrative purposes.

Your code is not written to handle failures or missing data. Consider (noting all the differences with what you posted):

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");
$response = array();

$reservation_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['reservation_id']);
$guest_last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['guest_last_name']);

$query = "SELECT reservation_id, guest_full_name
  , guest_last_name unit_number, floor, key_sa 
  FROM reservations2 
  INNER JOIN guest 
  ON (reservations2.reservation_id=guest.reservation_idg) 
  INNER JOIN unit USING (unit_id) 
  WHERE reservation_id ='".$reservation_id."'
    AND guest_last_name ='".$guest_last_name."";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (!$result) {
      $response['status']=503
      $response['msg']="Error";
      trigger_error(mysql_error());
      finish($response);
      exit;
}

$response['status']=200;
$response['msg']='OK';
$response['guest_full_name'] = htmlentities($_GET['guest_last_name']);
$response['reservations']=array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $response['reservations'][]=array(
           'unit_number'=>$row['unit_number'],
           'floor'=>$row['floor'],
           'key_sa'=>$row['floor_sa']);
  }
}
finish($response);
exit;

function finish($response)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 $response[status] $response[msg]");
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo  json_encode($response, true); 
}
```

Comment: The only other suggestion I would give is to use prepared statements to cut out the need for `mres` and to improve the security.

Comment: @amina90 If you have a new question, please [ask it](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) - after spending time yourself debugging and researching - rather than asking follow up questions here.

Comment: @Rob, the question relates to the code above. I am discussing the errors I am getting when using the code symcbean provided above. Also I did debug my code, and that's the error I am getting.